# Speeding Up Material UI nested List

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui

I have three nested Material UI lists in a slide out drawer, and each list contains about 8 items. I'm wrapping them in the Mui link component to use React Router. Based on what I've read online about pure components, I've also made my own pure component to try and speed up the performance, though I'm a beginner with them and I'm not sure if they're a good addition here (partly because how the MUI components are actually working is abstracted). 
At any rate, I was wondering if anyone had any idea about how I could increase the performance on this?

Here's the code:

One of the three list items:

```
 <List
      onClick={props.stopProp}
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <ListItem
        className={`${
          props.area == "uc" ? classes.active : classes.inactive
        } ${classes.uc}`}
        button
        onClick={() => handleClick("uc")}
      >
        <div className={classes.keeptext}>
          <ListItemText className={classes.topnested} primary="UC" />
        </div>
        {props.open ? (
          openLists.uc ? (
            <ExpandMore className={classes.keepright} />
          ) : (
            <ExpandLess className={classes.keepright} />
          )
        ) : null}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={openLists.uc} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          {listItems.uc.map(el => (
            <Link component={RouterLink} to={el.url}>
              <MyListItem name={el.name} classes={classes} icon={el.icon} open={props.open}/>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Collapse>
```

and then the MyListItem component:

```
const MyListItem = React.memo(({ name, classes, icon, open }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        {icon}
      </ListItemIcon>
       <ListItemText primary={name} className={ `${open ? classes.viewText : classes.invisText} ${classes.listItemText}`} />
    </ListItem>
  );
});
```

EDIT: The bad performance is a shuddering behaviour when I expand the lists. Generally the drawer is less responsive too. I've tried to remove the Link components which does improve performance, but I need them their so that the items actually have a point.

Comment: What's the performance "issue' and what have you tried/researched?

Comment: Hi Sung, sorry I edited the question and didn't make it clear  - there is some janky behaviour when I expand the nested lists. I've tried getting rid of the Link components that are rendered in the map function, and that did work, but I need them. I tried moving them into the MyListItem component but that made performance worse. Currently I'm trying to see if I can remove the dropdown animation on the list...

Comment: I don't think you can do anything to make it more efficient other mapping the list items with the unique keys.

Comment: Thanks Sreeram, I'll try that. I've also wrapped the drawer in a memoized component and that's speeded things up quite well.